# Cant find page after POST redirect C#

Tags: c#, post, razor

I go to a View, submit data via POST, but the redirect cannot find the Controller method. What am I doing wrong here? After submitting the form I get:

```
404 error: cannot find page. URL is:  http://localhost:52008/InternalController/UpdateCardFormPost
```

Snippet from InternalController.cs:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCardFormView()
{
    var CardToUpdate = new CardView();
    return View(CardToUpdate);//return implementation of Cards.cshtml with the empty model that was passed to it
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UpdateCardFormPost(CardView c)
{
    CardModelIO.WriteCard(c);//@TODO: IMPLEMENT

    return View("CardDetailView", c);
}
```

UpdateCardFormView.cshtml (the view with the form I am submitting):

```
@using LeanKit.API.Client.Library.TransferObjects
@model CardView

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--Form used to change a card
    STARTING DISPLAY called by in Internal/UpdateCardFormView
    ENDING DISPLAY (post) called by UpdateCardForm in InternalController a specified below-->
<head>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.BeginForm("UpdateCardFormPost", "InternalController", FormMethod.Post)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.AssignedUserName);
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />

</body>
</html>
```

Heres the CardDetailView.cshtml (the view I should be redirected to):

```
@using LeanKit.API.Client.Library.TransferObjects
@model IEnumerable<CardView>
<!--used for displaying an individual card in detail view
    referenced in UpdateCardFormPost() method of Internal controller-->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    CardView j = Model;
    <p>j.AssignedUserId</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified the controller name as InternalController but it's probably just called "Internal".

Try changing

`@Html.BeginForm("UpdateCardFormPost", "InternalController", FormMethod.Post)`

to

`@Html.BeginForm("UpdateCardFormPost", "Internal", FormMethod.Post)`

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately the controller was actually named `InternalController`

Comment: So in the Solution Explorer does the filename appear as "InternalControllerController"?

Comment: No, are you saying that the word controller is automatically appended? That would certainly explain my issue drat

Comment: Yes, kind of.  I think by convention controller classes are expected to be called "FooController" (and the file would be called FooController.cs), but when referring to it in code like in your Html.BeginForm line you just refer to it as "Foo".

Answer (score 0):

you are missing closing form tag

you should do it like

```
using (@Html.BeginForm("UpdateCardFormPost", "InternalController", FormMethod.Post))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.AssignedUserName);
<input type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />
```

}